# How to persist virtual attributes across validation errors and form redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up an autocomplete association following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised?view=asciicast).

I'm using `find_or_initialize` rather than `find_or_create` on the virtual category_name attribute, as I need to pass the value through some other logic.

What is the best way to persist this virtual attribute if the parent model validations fail (Product in the railscast). I want the `category_name` entered by the user to remain after the save path renders the form if there is an error.

I thought the value would be accessible through `params[:category_name]`, but I am unable to set it back to the field.

Grateful for any ideas.

**EDIT**

Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:prerep])

    if @products.save
      DO SOME STUFF...

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      end

    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Prerep < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ..., :category_name, ... 
  attr_reader ...
  attr_accessor ...

  belongs_to :user, :category

  has_many ...

  validates ...

  def category_name
    category.try(:name)
  end  

  def category_name=(name)
    product_category = Category.find_or_initialize_by_name(name) if name.present?
    self.category = if product_category.new_record?
      product_category ...SET SOME ATTRIBUTES...
      product_category.save(:validate => false)
      product_category
    else
      product_category
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is the redirection, why can't you render instead?

Comment: hi @apneadiving, sorry for my poorly worded question. The controller is actually rendering the form on eror, not redirecting. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd answer this question since I am having the exact same problem and I cannot find a single answer.

The best way is to manually validate everything that you need to validate. So instead of having the `validates` filter to do it, you have to do it in the controller yourself. So if your attributes are username, phone, and email, don't do `validates :email, presence: true` in the model, but rather do it manually in your controller. This way if you have extra parameters, you can just add another validate method in your controller or its helper to do the validation and it give you a chance to persist this.

Hopefully this saves people time since there does not seem to be an easier way to solve the problem. I mean, rails already speeds up our development time a lot anyways, a few more lines of code isn't going to kill us ;)